# No matching function for call to 'sqrt' in XCode 4.3

Tags: c++, macos, xcode4, standard-library

I'm trying to make an SDL game for Mac using C++. I've got everything SDL-related working fine, but when I try and use the sqrt function I get the error `no matching function for call to 'sqrt'`. Here's my list of includes and my first function (the main() function doesn't really do anything right now):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "geometry.h"

using namespace std;

void drawLine(vector2 start, vector2 end)
{
    double x = end.x - start.x;
    double y = end.y - start.y;
    double length = sqrt(x*x, y*y); // I get the error here
}
```

I've also tried importing  with the same results. Is there anything special I have to do on Mac (Lion, XCode 4.3) to get this working?

EDIT: for completeness, geometry.h contains the definition for the vector2 struct

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`sqrt`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man3/sqrt.3.html) only takes one argument.  You are giving it two.  Perhaps you meant to do this:

```
double length = sqrt(x*x + y*y);
```

Or did you confuse sqrt with [hypot](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/hypot)?

Comment: Thanks - can't believe I didn't spot that myself. I need some coffee.

Answer (score 2):

sqrt has only one argument, according to [Opengroup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sqrt.html)